# Multiple answers for the same limit expression?

Tags: calculus, limits

So I was trying to find the limit of the following expression.
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{\sin^3 x}$$
When using the L'Hospital's rule I got the answer $\frac {1}{2}$.

My steps:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{\sin^3 x} $$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sec^2 x - \cos x}{3\sin^2 x \cos x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2 \sec^2 x \tan x + \sin x}{6\sin x \cos^2 x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2 \sec^2 x \tan x}{6\sin x \cos^2 x}+\frac{\sin x}{6\sin x \cos^2 x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{3\cos^5 x}+\frac{1}{6\cos^2 x}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

Edit: My steps are incorrect from the 3rd line onward as pointed out by @Fishbane in the comments

Just to check my answer I substituted $x = 0.000000001$ and so on, on my calculator just to be sure, but I got the result to be $0$. Believing it to be some kind of error I used [WolframAlpha's calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=if+x%3D0.000000001+%28tan+x+-+sin+x%29%2F%28sin+x%29%5E3+)  as well and got the same result, $0$.

What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Can you show your steps in arriving at the answer $1/2$?

Comment: sure, i'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: your result of $\frac{1}{2}$ is correct, you probably made a mistake while checking.

Comment: @briantung edited!

Comment: Were you using degrees (a big no-no) or radians (as it should be) when you used your calculator?

Comment: @MasB I tried using radians and degrees, giving the same result, 0.

Comment: As @RossMillikan points out in his answer, the culprit is numerical error (which would happen whether you used radians or degrees). To get around this, you can work with the expression a bit:
$$\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{\sin^3 x} = \frac{1 - \cos x}{\sin^2 x \cos x}$$
From here, the trick is to multiply the top and bottom by $1+\cos x$, ultimately giving $\frac{1}{\cos x (1+\cos x)}.$ This addresses the numerical error, and also (presto!) you no longer need the sledgehammer that is L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Yeah! That looks much easier to do. Thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't actually affect the answer but as far as I can tell your third line is incorrect (assuming you used L'Hospital). The denominator should be $6 \sin(x) \cos^2(x)-3\sin^3(x)$.

Comment: Nice catch @Fishbane, now I am lost on how to proceed using L'Hospital... I'll just use the method Théophile suggested.

Comment: @Théophile You do not need to apply the trick: just use $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ in the denominator.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Good catch; that works too.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc but don't we have $\sin^3 x$ in the denominator? Or do I split it as $\sin x (1 - \cos^2 x)$

Comment: @Aditya In my first comment above, I wrote "From here, the trick is..."; it is at this point that you could instead replace $\sin^2 x$ with $1-\cos^2 x$. Then cancel a factor of $1-\cos x$ from the top and bottom, and you'll end up with the same result of $\frac 1{(\cos x)(1+\cos x)}$; this way is just a bit more direct than what I had.

Comment: @Théophile ah yes, got it now. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running into numerical error from the difference of two close numbers.  For small $x, \tan x - \sin x$ is about $\frac {x^3}2$ by the Taylor series while $\tan x$ and $\sin x$ are about $x$.  For $x=10^{-9}$ this is about $0.5 \cdot 10^{-27}$, which is $18$ orders of magnitude smaller than the terms you are subtracting.  Due to the limited precision of computer numbers, the difference comes out $0$.  Try with $x=10^{-3}$ instead and you get $\frac 12$ as you should from [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=if%20x%3D0.001%20%28tan%20x%20-%20sin%20x%29%2F%28sin%20x%29%5E3%20)

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, is the error just due to the computer's inability to calculate those values precisely enough?

Comment: Yes, although inability is too strong.  The computer is capable of doing it, but normally uses the standard floating point numbers which are not precise enough.  With a more sophisticated program it can do so.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) has a discussion.  It is a huge topic in numerical analysis

Comment: @Aditya For fun: let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\cos x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}$, for example. Mathematically, they are the same function, but numerically, one of them is much more stable. See what happens in your calculator with $f(0.000001)$ vs. $g(0.000001)$. You can manually calculate the numerator and denominator in each case to get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Understood @RossMillikan, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Théophile, yeah I get f(x)=0.5 but g(x)=0